# How to hide the valdiation message without form in angular

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have two date pickers and a search button. When I select the first datepicker and without selecting the second datepicker , when I then click the search button I will call the function to show the validation message.

After that when I select the second datepicker, the message should be hidden, but it doesn't.

How can I hide the validation message when I select the second datepicker?

```
if ($scope.fromdatepicker || $scope.fromdatepicker === null || angular.isUndefined($scope.fromdatepicker)) {
    $scope.toDateErrMsg = "please select an Effective To Date";
    $scope.fromclass = 'errormsg';
    $scope.toDateErrorMsg = true;
    alert("please choose To Date");
    isValidDateSearch = false;
}
```

And I bind the error message like this

```
<span class="errormsg"
      ng-show="{toDateErrorMsg}"
      ng-bind-html="toDateeErrMsg">
</span>
```

Comment: what is $scope variable name for 'toDate' calendar box.?

Comment: <input name="fromdate" ng-model="fromdatescope"/><input name="todate" ng-model="todate"/>

Comment: the problem is when select the first datepicker , doesnt select second means when click the search , i call the function to show the message. then i am selct 2 datepicker , its not hide.

Comment: check whether $scope.todate has value or not. based on that, you show/hide message

Comment: how can i check that without form   name can i give $scope.datepickername.

Comment: It is good to understand if you can make fiddle.

Comment: ok .. can i call the function in ng-touch  ="{check()}"

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct binding.

```
ng-show="{toDateErrorMsg}"
```

Should be

```
ng-show="toDateErrorMsg"
```

As [per the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow). Also remember that you need to set `toDateErrorMsg` to a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value in order for it to be hidden.

You will most likely have gotten an exception which you can see in the console window in most browsers by clicking F12, or C-M-i (depending on OS and browser).